# get all links from one node in HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, href

I'm trying to get all the links that are linked to one node, having a structure like:

```
<li class="" data-vc-node-id="10"><span><i></i></span>
    <a href="A" ><i></i><span></span></a>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="B"></a>

                        </li>                   
                        <li>
                            <a href "C"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="D"></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>       
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

I would like all the links from "*data-vc-node-id="10"*" and I'm trying to get them doing something like:

```
for tag in soup.findAll('data-vc-node-id="10"',href=True):
   print tag
```

But of course, I'm getting nothing from that :/

How can I get them?

Thanks!

Comment: Not a node.js question.

Comment: this `href "C"` is incorrect attribute. A typo?

Answer (score 1):

With `BeautifulSoup.select()` method:

```
...
for el in soup.select('li[data-vc-node-id="10"] a'):
    print(el)
```

The output:

```
<a href="A"><i></i><span></span></a>
<a href="B"></a>
<a href="C"></a>
<a href="D"></a>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! but with this I only get the first one :( is it posible to get only the 'A', 'B', 'C'? the links exactly and only

Comment: @JoelSánchezLópez, I've tested on your input and it works fine (on Python 3.5)